# Is it possible to restrict editing of certain file types [like css] in visual studio or specifically TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sass, less, ironruby

My question is in big environment preferably would like to lockdown people from editing the generated CSS files instead of in our case .scss files.

Highly recommend anyone who is using Visual Studio for front end development to check out Web Workbench plugin, that allows you to takeadvantage of precompiling CSS with SASS/LESS and javascript with CoffeeScript. You will need to install IronRuby but both are very easy installs.

Comment: If your .css files are generated, then you should consider not checking them in. You don't check in .exe files, do you?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through the Check-in policies that come with the Team Foundation Server Power Tools. There's a [forbiddenpattern policy](https://rerrify.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/ignoring-files-from-team-foundation-server-check-ins-4/) that will prevent checking in files that match a specific pattern.

If needed, you can combine this with the [Custom path policy](http://Custom%20Path%20Policy) to scope these blocked patterns to specific locations (so that you can check in the compiled result into certain folders, but not just anywhere)

You can overrule either rule, if you want, but need to provide a reason comment for that. [These overrides can be monitored](http://colinsalmcorner.blogspot.com/2011/03/monitoring-check-in-policy-overrides.html).

[More information on Check in policies](https://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/06/14/available-check-in-policies-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx).